# Eclipse Broke After uninstalling old Java version

Tags: java, eclipse

I was using eclipse and Java recommended me to delete the old version (I think it was jre10 ...). Now when I load eclipse it kept giving me an error and telling me to check the log file. I have now deleted eclipse from my computer and installed e(fx)clipse. The same error is occuring and I am not sure how to fix it. 
Log file:

https://pastebin.com/8n8ziUrW

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
javax/annotation/PostConstruct
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You need either a newer version of Eclipse, or to run it with an older release of Java. Java 9 deprecated and Java 11 removed the `javax.annotation` package, among others.

Comment: I deleted the e(fx)clipse and installed eclipse again but with a newer version and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @helppls1452132 Then you should click the checkmark next to this answer to accept it, so we all can see that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.